# What happened to the modifications to the Enterprise made by the Kelvans?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, warp

In the TOS Episode *By Any Other Name*, the Kelvans make enhancements to the *Enterprise*, allowing it to travel at far greater speeds than it normally could (it passed warp 11 from memory).  I was wondering then is there any further reference to these modifications being removed from the Enterprise/studied by Starfleet (I don't mind if these are referred to in TOS or onwards, although I'd expect it'd only be discussed in TOS), or was this just ignored as at the next episode?

Comment: The warp page on memory alpha said that the enterprise-a could travel up to warp 12 after their refit

Comment: This is all of course before a strictly-enforced Warp 10 limit was put in place...clearly they were using a different Warp Scale in Kirk's era.

Comment: @Zibbobz [Yep](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/35539/2242)

Comment: Do you care about the trek books because the "corp of engineers" series has several bits about the Kelvan modifications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They were forgotten by the next episode and never mentioned again. I would assume that the in-universe explanation would be that the Kelvans took them out again at the end of the episode, which would explain the lack of reference to them in the future, but this is just conjecture. *TOS* had very poor continuity.

Answer (score 5):

#### OFFICIALLY: No record of what was done with the Kelvan technology is ever made. But I doubt the technology was lost. More than likely what could be salvaged was taken for study by Federation scientists.

**A bold statement but one confirmed by an episode of ST:TNG called "Where No One Has Gone Before"**

[image]

In Memory Alpha's [Continuity](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/By_Any_Other_Name_%28episode%29#Continuity) reference to "[A Rose by Any Other Name](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/By_Any_Other_Name_%28episode%29)"

> - Kirk mentions that an intergalactic voyage by a 23rd century starship would take "thousands of years" to reach the Andromeda Galaxy. For the Kelvans, intergalactic travel is a three-century journey.
> - In the 24th century, as seen in TNG: "Where No One Has Gone Before", Federation technology has apparently matched the Kelvans, perhaps due to this encounter, when it is discussed that a return trip to the Milky Way from the Triangulum Galaxy would take three hundred years at maximum warp.

Comment: The interesting thing about that is that the Triangulum Galaxy is further away than Andromeda. Still, this need not be due to Kelvan technology. I would also assume that if the *Enterprise* had been fitted with Kelvan technology, the ship would have been taken by Star Fleet for study, not allowed to continue its five-year mission. Three hundred years at maximum warp also contradicts the length of time *Voyager* would take to return to Earth. It seems to be another case of poor continuity among *Trek* writers. Perhaps it could be explained by wormholes on the voyage from Triangulum.