# How was warp 44 achieved in Star Trek: The Animated Series, when warp 10 was impossible in later series?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, warp, star-trek-the-animated-series

In the *Star Trek: The Animated Series* episode, "The Counter-Clock Incident", the Enterprise is on an assignment to facilitate one of the earliest captains of the Enterprise, who'd reached involuntary retirement age. On the way, they pass through a nebula which looks beautiful on the outside but is extremely deadly if ventured near to.

Suddenly, they see a ship approaching, which is seemingly at warp 45. They try to slow it down with their tractor beam, which has hardly any effect on the renegade ship, but increases their own speed to warp 44 or so. (The rest of the episode, where they go into a backward universe to Karli's (the ship's captain) home planet "Arret", which I am guessing is backwards for Terra, is not of much importance here).

The real question is, when Janeway and her team achieved warp 10 in the *Voyager* episode, "Threshold", they turned into sloths, while these guys didn't even when going to four times that speed. Is this just a direction issue or something else?

Comment: Related, if not an outright dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35539/warp-13-was-this-overlooked Also related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/why-did-the-star-trek-writers-decide-warp-10-would-be-infinite

Comment: @LogicDictates - I agree. Earlier shows didn't have Warp 10 as a hard barrier

Comment: They call Warp 10 whatever is considered to be the current limit of technology. At one point they realized they can go faster. Imagine measuring everything in "running horse speeds" then inventing a car that can go twice as fast as a horse. Then three times. Then four. At one point, you rename "running horse speed" to mean something else.

Comment: Some things are possible in [cartoon physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartoon_physics) that are impossible elsewhere.

Comment: @kesarling He-Him  Actually I believe the highest warp factor number ever mentioned was Warp Factor 37 in "The Counter Clock Incident".  The TOS and the TNG era warp scales are different.  According to the official TOS warp scale - which, however, was never established in canon - warp factor 10 would be 1,000 times the speed of light, warp factor 37 would be 50,653 times the speed of light, and warp factor 44 would be 85,184 times the speed of light.  And Warp factor 10 on the TNG scale is said to be infinitely fast and so much faster than those TOS warp factors.